# CSS selector of inner elements

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors

I'm want to select the words "Dashboard", "Attendance", "Marcum" and "Results" and set their color to White.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


                <div class="fpstartwrap">
                <div class="fpstart">
                    <div class="iconset">

                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net" title="Dashboard" 
                                   alt="Dashboard" target="_blank">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-home"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Dashboard
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net/attendance" 
                                   title="Attendance" alt="Attendance" target="_blank">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-user-times"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Attendance
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net/q" title="Marcum" 
                                      alt="Marcum" target="_parent">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-calculator"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Marcum
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net/user/" title="Results" 
                                       alt="Results" target="_self">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-id-card-o"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Results
                                </a>
                            </div>


                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="collapse" id="fpslider">
                        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net">Rafiee.net</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net/attendance">Attendance</a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net/dailybonus">Daily Bonus</a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net/q">Marcum Calculator</a>
    </div>
</div>
                    </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>



</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to do it by :

```
div a[role="button"] {
color: white;
}
```

However, since I have other elements with role "Button", they are all changed to white which is undesirable in my case. I only need to target these four words. Is it possible? Any help is appreciated in advance.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parent elements in the selector to be more specific:

```
.fpstartwrap > .fpstart > .iconset > div.btn.btn-secondary a[role="button"] {
  color: white;
}
```

Or simply apply a class to those buttons which you only use for these four buttons and use that class in your selector.

Answer (score 1):

To get a CSS selector to only act on a button inside a div use `>` this tells CSS to get all elements that have a parent div and role=button:

```
div > a[role="button"] {
  color: white;
}
```

if you really need to be specific then you can even just add a special class to the buttons you wanna act on like

```
 <a class="whiteButton" role="button" href="https://rafiee.net/attendance" title="Attendance" alt="Attendance" target="_blank">
```

Then for the CSS you can do

```
.whiteButton {
}

or if only whiteButton inside of div's

div > .whiteButton {
}

or even

div > a > .whiteButton {
}
```

```css
div > a[role="button"]{
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


                <div class="fpstartwrap">
                <div class="fpstart">
                    <div class="iconset">

                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net" title="Dashboard" 
                                   alt="Dashboard" target="_blank">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-home"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Dashboard
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net/attendance" 
                                   title="Attendance" alt="Attendance" target="_blank">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-user-times"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Attendance
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net/q" title="Marcum" 
                                      alt="Marcum" target="_parent">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-calculator"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Marcum
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a role="button" href="https://rafiee.net/user/" title="Results" 
                                       alt="Results" target="_self">
                                    <div class="navicon" align="center">
                                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-id-card-o"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Results
                                </a>
                            </div>


                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="collapse" id="fpslider">
                        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net">Rafiee.net</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net/attendance">Attendance</a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net/dailybonus">Daily Bonus</a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://rafiee.net/q">Marcum Calculator</a>
    </div>
</div>
                    </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>



</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the first approach, still targets other elements which I don't want them to be included. I need more specific. Considering second approach, I'm not sure it's possible, since I don't access to the core code. I want to add css to Extra CSS section of my theme, so I don't think I can add extra class to an existing elemen, could I ?

Comment: I updated the code with a snippet. What extra elements are being gotten that you aren't trying to get. I thought you just want " Dashboard", "Attendance", "Marcum" and "Results". The first way I did it only gets those elements

Comment: Also you can add extra classes to existing elements if you are willing to use Javascript. If you are trying to strictly use CSS and HTML then no you cant add class elements